# Installing C - programming software

Tags: c

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.10, and I am new using Linux. What software do I need to install to do C-programming?

I am looking for a compiler and libraries. I'm not only new in Linux, but also in C as you can see. I've learned to install compiler using `sudo apt-get install g++`. And "Hello world" works just fine. :)

I guess it contains all basic libraries, but how do I install additional ones?  Especially I need `grace`.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? An IDE, a compiler, a linker, standard libraries ...? I mean, programming can be done with pen and paper strictly speaking, so please be more specific in what you need.

Comment: Programming IS done with pen+paper @gertvdijk coding on the other hand ;-)  And Daniel: you can already start coding with a plain install: `gedit` is there as an editor (and provides syntax highlighting)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't specific enough, I was looking for compiler and libraries. I'm not only new in Linux, but also in C as you can see. I've learned to install compiler using 'sudo apt-get install g++' command in install. And "Hello world" works just fine. :) I guess it contains all basic libraries, but how do I install aditional ones?

Comment: @Daniel Which libraries do you need ?

Comment: I needed 'grace' and Terminal instructed me. Still learning basics so I guess I won't be needing any for certain amount of time. Guys, thank you very much for your readiness to help. :)

Comment: Please provide additional information only by editing your question and not in a comment.

Comment: I have brought the additional information from your comments into your question - now would be the time to remove the comments (and maybe edit your question with further details).

Answer (score 3):

I use codeblocks. I would recommend you the same. 
Maybe you need to install build-essentials to compile programs.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 2):

The GNU toolchain (`gcc`, `binutils`, `make`, etc.) and a text editor (`gedit`, `nano`, `vim`, etc.). You most likely already have those.

If you want to use IDEs' then, Geany is one of the simpler ones.

Answer (score 2):

You need a text editor and a compiler

Use gcc as compiler and gedit as the texteditor, If you prefer an Integrated Development Environment try codeblocks or eclipse with cdt

Answer (score 1):

You should use text editor, compiler and a Version control tool.

For Text Editor, sublime-text-3 is best for developers and also you can use many themes and autocomplete plugin on it. It has package manager that will help you to install these plugins.

These are the commands to install the [package manager](https://packagecontrol.io/)

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y sublime-text-installer
```

For compiler, you can install gcc and g++ for command line.

For version control, use git.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install build-essential for C programming:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

I usually use Geany, but gedit or any other text-editor will do fine

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a gnome baesed distro I would also suggest Ajunta for an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Visual studio code for an IDE. It has in-built terminal and debugger. You can install it by the mentioned link :
https://code.visualstudio.com/download
Choose debian package for installation on ubuntu